# Hyphenation in german

Tags: babel, hyphenation, german

I'm writing a large document, where I will have a single page in german. On that page the hyphenation does not work correcetly. Also by using `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` I have some issues with umlauts. Does anyone know how to solve that problem, probably by just changing some document properties on that single page only?

Comment: You have also `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, don't you?

Comment: I tried that, but I want to avoid it, as it's changing the font and the whole document looks strange...

Comment: How about `\begin{otherlanguage}{ngerman} Deutscher Teil \end{otherlanguage}`?

Comment: Therefore I have to include %\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}%  as well, don't I? A next problem arising is, that all Figures are labeled by ``Abbildung'' now.

Comment: Please, make an example where hyphenation fails. Without it we can only guess.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using pdfLaTeX, you may want to use the following template to organize the language-related typographic matters. (Note that `ngerman` is specified before `english` when `babel` is loaded.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
Once upon a time \dots

\begin{otherlanguage}{ngerman}

Es war einmal \dots

\end{otherlanguage}

Back to English.
\end{document}
```

If you're using LuaLaTeX, the following template is more appropriate.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
Once upon a time \dots

\begin{otherlanguage}{ngerman}

Es war einmal \dots

\end{otherlanguage}

Back to English.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and sorry for the late reply. I'm using PDFLatex. Your idea works, but somehow the font changes (to something like a typewriter font). BTW, I'm using the Thesis template by Steven Gunn (http://www.sunilpatel.co.uk/thesis-template/).